# incoming MMS notification

Tags: android

can we receive notification if user received an MMS?

Comment: I am doing something similar HERE!!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21748209/receive-mms-messages-in-android-kitkat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is example of this issue

http://code.google.com/p/android-notifier/

Answer (score 1):

The android-notifier link appears to be broken currently.

see http://code.google.com/p/android-smspopup/ for an example of this.